# local variable 'num1' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x

The error:

```
local variable 'num1' referenced before assignment.
```

I tried making a separate function but it did not work (or at least I could not get it to work).

```
def main():

  while True:
    try:
      num1=int(input('.+'))

    except ValueError:
      print('Sorry, this progam only accepts values between 0 and 100.')
    if num1 < 0:
      return ('Sorry this program only accepts values between 0 and 100.')
    else:
      break 

  if num1 >= 90:
    return ('Your letter grade is A')
  if num1 >= 80:
    return ('Your letter grade is B')
  elif num1 >= 70:
    return ('Your letter grade is C')
  elif num1 >= 60:
    return ('Your letter grade is D')
  if num1 <=60:
    return ('Your letter grade is F')

print(main())
```

Comment: This is a repl.it assignment given to me by my computer science instructor so the .+ is just because repl.it is weird sometimes

Comment: Your code is working fine. What's the issue?

Comment: Can you post the traceback for better explanation of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens if you enter an invalid number the first time. The variable `num1` never gets defined in that case.

To solve this you could define the variable once outside the while loop, maybe like this:

```
num1 = -1
while True:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume this happens when you input a string that can't be cast to an int. So it enters the try block, then (without setting num1) throws an exception, and moves on. Later you try to access num1, which wasn't set.

You can set a default to the num:

```
while True:
    try:
        num1 = int(input())
    except ValueError:
        num1 = -1

    if num < 0:
        print('Please input a valid number between 0 - 100')
    else:
        break
```

This will make it only warn the user once per invalid input and keep prompting until they input a valid number

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned the code a bit.

```
def my_func():

  while True:
    try:
      this_input=int(input('.+'))
    except ValueError:
      print('Sorry, this progam only accepts values between 0 and 100.')
    if this_input < 0 or this_input > 100:
      return ('Sorry this program only accepts values between 0 and 100.')
    else:
      break 

  if this_input >= 90:
    return ('Your letter grade is A')
  elif this_input >= 80:
    return ('Your letter grade is B')
  elif this_input >= 70:
    return ('Your letter grade is C')
  elif this_input >= 60:
    return ('Your letter grade is D')
  elif this_input <=60:
    return ('Your letter grade is F')
  elif this_input > 100:
    return ("Value out of bounds")
  else:
    return ""


print(my_func())
```

You're getting an error because you enter something other than an int.

```
daudnadeem:use_me_to_code_tests daudn$ python3 mail.py
.+A
Sorry, this progam only accepts values between 0 and 100.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mail.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(my_func())
  File "mail.py", line 9, in my_func
    if this_input < 0 or this_input > 100:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'this_input' referenced before assignment
daudnadeem:use_me_to_code_tests daudn$ python3 mail.py
.+100
Your letter grade is A
```